# What problems cause Visual Studio to say "Source information is missing from the debug information for this module"?

Tags: visual-studio, .net-core, compiler-construction, code-generation, pdb-files

I'm working on a compiler for the CLR, and I mostly have it working.  I'm trying to generate debug information, and I can get it to create an embedded PDB in the generated assembly where all the debug metadata looks right.  When I load the assembly, the Modules view says "Symbols loaded."  But I can't get the debugger to recognize breakpoints, and if I throw an exception inside the code, it says,

> ## Source Not Available
>
> Source information is missing from the debug information for this module.

When I look at the assembly in DotPeek, it does not say "Debug" on the assembly's main name line, the way it does for C# assemblies built with debug information.  I'm not sure what's missing, though.

What can cause this error to come up?  In case anyone needs a test case to look at, [here's one.](https://github.com/boo-lang/boo/files/7834321/testcase.zip)

**EDIT:** Please read the question and take note of the Tags.  I've gotten a couple different answers on here that are bog-standard "how to get PDBs to load under normal circumstances" answers.  *This question is not about normal circumstances.*  I am building the compiler and it is generating incorrect PDBs.  I need a way to debug the output of the PDB code that I am generating myself.

Comment: There are several other questions asking about this error.  As near as I can tell, this is not a duplicate of any of them, as they're all about troubleshooting third-party software that they can't debug, whereas in mine I'm the one who created the debug information and I'm trying to fix my own codegen.